# using jquery with reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I just need to add a count down clock for my website home page. I'm using meteor and reactjs. When I put it in to componentDidMount, sometimes it's working sometimes it's not. I also have a javascript slider. Sometimes I got "countdown is not a function" error message in my console. How can I make my code working?

```
  componentDidMount () {
    // The counter
    function countDown(){
      $('#clock').countdown('2016/9/9', function (event) {
        var $this = $(this).html(event.strftime(''
         + '<span>%m</span> months '
         + '<span>%w</span> weeks '
         + '<span>%d</span> days '
         + '<span>%H</span> hr '
         + '<span>%M</span> min '
         + '<span>%S</span> sec'));
      });
    }

    // The background image slide
    $('body').vegas({
      slides: [
        { src: '/images/slides/slide1.jpg' },
        { src: '/images/slides/slide2.jpg' },
        { src: '/images/slides/slide3.jpg' },
      ],
      cover:              true,
      animation:          'random',
      transition:         'fade',
      transitionDuration: 2500,
      overlay:            '/images/slides/overlay.png',
    });

    // The counter
    countDown();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When each time your countdown ticks, you need to update your state and react will re-render your view according to state change. The reason of your saying "sometimes it works, sometimes it does not" is that the react will update its view only when the state or props changes. In addition, you need to do the same thing for your slider as well. Another point is that manipulation of DOM manually in react (in most cases) is a bad practise because the reconciliation / diffing mechanism will be meaningless when you do your changes directly on the DOM. You need to adopt your view changes to React's component lifecycle methods